# Angular UI Dropdown issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In firefox, UI Bootstrap's dropdown won't let me click on child elements, that is, it shows the dropdown menu, but it seems to be in background the very last in layers and my clicks won't get to its layer, I tried with z-index on ul, li and etc, but this doesn't work.

Also, I don't have this problem in Chrome, the code works as expected there.

```
                        <div id="myDropdownMenu" >
                            <button uib-dropdown  uib-dropdown-toggle class="btn btn-default menu-btn" title="Menu">
                                <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
                                    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="menuitem in vm.dropdownmenu" ng-click="vm.onDropdownMenuClick(menuitem.value)">
                                        <span class="dropdown-item">{{menuitem.label}}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="font-size: 32px;"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I faced this issue before on Firefox. The fix was basically adjusting the position and z-index of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that by using uib-dropdown's *dropdown-append-to-body*

> dropdown-append-to-body B (Default: false) - Appends the inner dropdown-menu to the body element.

Now the correct code looks like:

```
<div id="myDropdownMenu" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
                            <button class="btn btn-default menu-btn" uib-dropdown-toggle title="Меню">

                                <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
                                    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="menuitem in vm.dropdownmenu" ng-click="vm.onDropdownMenuClick(menuitem.value)">
                                        <span class="dropdown-item">{{menuitem.label}}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="font-size: 32px;"></span>

                            </button>
                        </div>
```

As I read in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), this option will add the inner dropdown-menu to the body, as I see it, without this parameter the dropdown menu floats somewhere without any relation to the layer on which it was created.

Would be beneficial if anyone can say why specifically this setting exists and when it's useful not to use.